# Which approaches are exists for using of possessive case in variables/classes/methods naming?

Tags: coding-style, naming, coding-standards, naming-standards

In variables/classes/methods naming, sometimes "of" preposition is omitted and word order changing, for example:

"Absolute path of source file of entry point" -> "entryPointSourceFileAbsolutePath"

Now I am considering the renaming of above variable to:

```
absolutePathOfSourceFileOfEntryPoints
```

Which other approaches exists for using of possessive case in variables/classes/methods naming?
And also, what the spread of approach with omitting of "of" preposition and word order changing, like "entryPointSourceFileAbsolutePath"?

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean „ownership“ when you write possessive? And not possessive forms like“mine“, „your“ „their“ ? In other words that it‘s about the Aof in AofB ?

Comment: @Christophe, The last one is right. I mean "XX of NN" construction.

Answer (score 3):

There is no commonly accepted standard about constructing a name out of several parts.

There is however a universally accepted practice of **avoiding names that are excessively long**.  This is why binding words are often omitted.

Moreover, the english practice of decreasing specificity from right to left is often used.  For example:

- a "short understandable variable name" is to be understood according to the following grouping `(short (understandable (variable (name))))`,  so the core name is on the right, and you add more and more details that are matter less and less to the left.
- `absolutePath` would be primarily about a path, which by the way is absolute.
- And `entryPointSourceFileAbsolutePath` is about a path that is absolute of a file containing source of a point of entry.

The last example shows the problem with longer names: they are more difficult to read,  but they also add more parts and therewith more combination possibilitites and ambiguities (e.g. `SourceFileAbsolutePath` is in reality to be grouped as `( (Source(File)) (Absolute(Path)) )` and not `(Source(File(Absolute(Path))))`

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume this depends on context and programming language:

For configuration data (your example looks like that), hierarchical naming is a possible option. YAML and TOML are established formats which can be parsed into maps or objects for simple access. Your example might look like `entryPoints.sourceFile.path` (omitting the likely redundant `absolute`) which I would consider sufficiently readable.

Within classes and methods, names shouldn't repeat redundant context information. For example, within an `EntryPointParser` class, it's obvious that you're talking about EntryPoints, no need to repeat that in method or variable names.